# Rotating an ImageOverlay specified with longitude/latitude corners in Open Street Maps in Flutter

Tags: flutter, openstreetmap, fluttermap

I have an image placed using flutter_map in Flutter, which is positioned using NW/SE corner longitude/latitudes. I need to rotate this image around its centre a specified number of degrees - I do this in Google Maps by simply rotating the image div using CSS, which works fine for our purposes. Flutter lets me rotate the OverlayImageLayer, but not individual overlayImages.

As I understand it flutter_map uses a third lng/lat to specify the lower left (SW) bounding box corner to control rotation, and possibly also needs new co-ordinates for the other two points.

In short I need to be able to specify an initial bounding box which is unrotated, and then recalculate the corner positions once rotated a specified number of degrees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68238528/rotate-a-object-in-latlng-coordinate-system) - each corner point should be rotated around a central point, this gives transformed LatLngs providing the overlay does not overlap the poles or span the international date line.

```
  LatLng rotateLatLng(LatLng coord, LatLng centre, double degRotation) {
    // Make this constant so it doesn't have to be repeatedly recalculated
    const piDiv180 = maths.pi / 180;

    // Convert the input angle to radians
    final r = (0-degRotation) * piDiv180;

    // Create local variables using appropriate nomenclature
    final x = coord.longitude;
    final y = coord.latitude;
    final mx = centre.longitude;
    final my = centre.latitude;

    // Offset input point by the midpoint so the midpoint becomes the origin
    final ox = x - mx;
    final oy = y - my;

    // Cache trig results because trig is expensive
    final cosr = maths.cos(r);
    final sinr = maths.sin(r);

    // Perform rotation
    final dx = ox * cosr - oy * sinr;
    final dy = ox * sinr + oy * cosr;

    // Undo the offset
    return LatLng(dy + my, dx + mx);
  }
```